# How to exchange data between Android services

Tags: android, service

I would like to know what is the best and fastest way to exchange data between services. I have been trying to bind one service to another using `ServiceConnection` but the actual connection never happened. Also I did not saw anything strange in LogCat.

Thanks in advance for all your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Intents and [bindService][1] are usually the best way to go.

Could you give more details regarding "the actual connection never happened"?

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService(android.content.Intent, android.content.ServiceConnection, int)